# Can sed remove successive newline characters?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a document with a lot of empty lines.

How can I remove them when there are two or more together?

I tried `sed "s/\n\n//"` file, didn't work.  No error.

Comment: Do I read you correctly if you do not want to remove all blank lines, but only if it is two or more. So not *single* blank lines?

Comment: And if it's two or more lines shall really all of them be deleted or just all but one?

Comment: You're only asking about replacing empty-lines (`^$`), not (escaped) double newlines within a line: `aaa\n\nbbb`?

Comment: Two 'empty' lines means `\n\n\n` all in a row, correct?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
sed '/^$/d'
```

`sed` is line-oriented, so thinking in terms of "2 or more of a particular byte" works, *except* when that byte is a newline.  Then you have to think of something that works for the entire line.

Comment: Of course! +1 for simple elegance.

Comment: `sed` is capable of handling several lines via its "pattern space" / "hold space" feature. But I feel that's too complicated. ;-)

Comment: This will not function as desired if the first character of the file is a newline.

Comment: @ChrisDown - are you certain?  I tried it on just such a file, and it seemed to work with (GNU sed) 4.2.2.

Comment: @BruceEdiger Note the first line -- http://sprunge.us/ATJZ

Comment: To make it work when the first character is a newline (if that's really a requirement), then you can enclose the command with a negative address `1!` (match all except line 1), thus: `sed  '1!{/^$/d'}`.

Comment: `sed  '/^$/d' file.txt > file.txt` results in an empty file.

Comment: @AaronFranke - yes, but that's a facet of how Linux shells treat '>' redirection. The shell looks at the command line, sees a '>' redirection of stdout to a file, creates that file, and only then runs `sed`.  Creating a file will essentially delete any existing file with the same name.  `sed '/^&/d' file.txt > otherfile.txt` will work.

Comment: This approach removes ALL empty lines, which is not what this question asked for. A much better answer is https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131228/48973

Answer (score 28):

No need for `sed`. `grep` will do:

```
grep .
```

(that's `grep`, SPC, dot, that is match any line containing at least one character).

There's also:

```
tr -s '\n'
```

(squeeze any sequence of newline characters into one).

As noted by Chris, both are not equivalent because removing empty lines (like the first solution above and most other answers focus on here) is not the same as squeezing sequences of newline characters as requested in the case where the first line is empty as it only takes **one** leading newline character to make the first line empty.

Comment: This will not function as desired if the first character of the file is a newline: http://sprunge.us/FLAJ

Comment: Can we only remove two newlines like `\n\n` and keep single newlines?

Comment: The task was not to remove all empty lines but to leave single empty lines alone and remove multiple consecutive empty lines, i.e. `\n{3,}` --> `\n\n`.

Comment: @Kusalananda, maybe the OP was wanting `cat -s` but they effectively asked to remove successive newline characters, so it's hard to tell what they really wanted all those years ago. Yet another XY Problem.

Answer (score 23):

If you wanted to keep a single blank line for any given sequence of blank lines you might do:

```
sed -e '/./b' -e :n -e 'N;s/\n$//;tn'
```

Comment: This is the only answer (besides `cat -s`) that actually accomplishes exactly what the question asked as I understand it. (And it's better than `cat -s` because I can use `sed -i` with it.)

Comment: could you explain it plz?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for CRLF.

Answer (score 12):

What do you mean remove? remove duplicate (many blank line to one) or remove all?

If you want to remove duplicate, here is the method using sed:

```
sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D'
```

It simulates `uniq` command.

The best choice is using `awk`:

```
awk NF <filename>
```

Comment: The `sed` part of this works great! Recommending this one as the best answer.

Comment: That sed command doesn't discriminate non-blank lines: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1444433/10580490

Answer (score 8):

For most of these answers it is first necessary to remove trailing whitespace.
Removing doubled up newlines removes all blank lines. (Think about this).

Literally interpreted the OP wants "all blank lines removed from a file if there are any repeated blank lines".

The typical user wants to "remove only duplicated blank lines".

To do this, strip trailing whitepace first, and pipe though cat -s

```
sed  s/[[:space:]]*$// | cat -s
```

And yet this will not remove a superflous leading or trailing blank line.

Answer (score 7):

<del>`sed` is not the best tool for that, since it is line based and treats `\n` as the end-of-line character this gets complicated.</del> Having seen @Bruce Ediger's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/76066/22222) `sed` may well be the perfect tool for the job, still, here are some other options:

1. Perl

   ```
   perl -ne 'print if /./' file.txt
   ```

   or

   ```
   perl -pe '$/=""; s/\n+/\n/;' file.txt
   ```

   Thanks to [@ruakh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/12378/ruakh) who made me go and read [this](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles):

   > $/
   >
   > The input record separator, newline by default. This influences Perl's idea of what a "line" is. Works like awk's RS variable, including treating empty lines as a terminator if set to the null string (an empty line cannot contain any spaces or tabs). You may set it to a multi-character string to match a multi-character terminator, or to undef to read through the end of file. Setting it to "\n\n" means something slightly different than setting to "" , if the file contains consecutive empty lines. **Setting to "" will treat two or more consecutive empty lines as a single empty line. Setting to "\n\n" will blindly assume that the next input character belongs to the next paragraph, even if it's a newline.**
2. gawk/awk

   ```
   awk '$1' file.txt
   ```

   That will work for the example posted but as [@Stephane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/stephane-chazelas) pointed out, it will also delete lines whose first field "looks like" `0`. This is more robust:

   ```
   awk NF file.txt
   ```

Comment: For Perl, `perl -pe 's/\n+/\n/ file.txt` will do, the input record separator is irrelevant for this use.

Comment: @vonbrand no, `perl -pe` or `perl -ne` work line by line. `\n+` will never match because it is only applied on a single line. That's why you need to either set `$/` or use `-0` ti slurp the file whole: `perl -0pe 's/\n+/\n/' file`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean up all lines that only have blank spaces and/or tabs by removing the spaces and tabs
2. Remove all DOUBLE blank lines (i.e. \n\n), while preserving at least one

To do so (with thanks to @cuonglm for part of the code)

```
sed 's|^[ \t]\+$||' your_filename | sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D'
```

Replace `your_filename` with the actual filename.

Comment: -1 : This removes any consecutive duplicate lines in addition to the redundant EOLs. So while this (otherwise helpful) command does respond to the OP, it is also data-destructive.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'slurp.subst(:global, / \n ** 3..* /, "\n\n").put;'   file
```

OR:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'lines.join("\n").subst(:global, / \n ** 3..* /, "\n\n").put;'   file
```

Above are answers written in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Raku features a Unicode-ready regex engine, and is certainly capable of performing newline substitutions.

The OP indicates that *two-or-more* consecutive blank lines (i.e. `\n\n\n` or longer) are dis-favored, and would prefer one blank line maximum (i.e. `\n\n`). In the Raku code above the file is either `slurp`ed into memory all at once, or `lines` are read-in and joined on `\n` (the second option might be more efficient/lazy). The `subst` requested is then `:global`ly performed, and the result is out`put`.

Sample Input:

```
Title

First Para.


Second Para.



End.
```

Sample Output:

```
Title

First Para.

Second Para.

End.
```

*NOTES:*

1. Caveats about a leading `\n` on the first line of a file apply to the Raku answers above. Use Raku's `trim-leading` routine if desired/necessary.
2. Any blank spaces within the `\n ** 3..*` 'three-or-more consecutive newlines' pattern will prevent recognition--and thus `subst`itution. To circumvent this (make regex tolerant of blank spaces), use the following Regex instead (`\h` stands for *horizontal whitespace*):_

/ `[ \n \h* ]+ \n` /

---

Finally, there seems to be some confusion as to the OP's desired outcome. To produce a result removing ***all*** blank lines (identical return as excellent answers by @terdon and @StéphaneChazelas), use the following Raku code:

```
#Similar to Perl:

~$ raku -ne '.put if /./;'  file
Title
First Para.
Second Para.
End.

#Similar to `grep`:

~$ raku -e '.put for lines.grep( *.chars );'  file
Title
First Para.
Second Para.
End.
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Regexes
https://raku.org

Answer (score -2):

Try `sed -e 's#\\n\\n#\\n#g' input.file > output.file` using `/` both as your field separator and part of your regex could be the problem.

Comment: Just gave this a whirl with one of my files containing double and triple newlines in a sequence. Doesn't work at all for me.

Answer (score -2):

If your file is using CRLF (DOS/Windows format) line-endings, try:

```
tr -s '\r' '\n'
```

Comment: yes, their answer didn't work for me.

Comment: AFAIK this answer is incorrect. I recommend yo to delete it.

Comment: oh, its because my file contains lots of newlines and carriage returns actually. 0x0d0a

Comment: Actually, the command removes repeated lines with windows end of line. Test with `echo -e 'one\r\n\r\n\r\n\rtwo'| tr -s '\r' '\n'`. The command `tr` will translate all `\r` to `\n` and then will squeeze all `\n` to just one. So, it works, not sure what to do with the fact that this apply to windows, not UNIX.

Comment: Works for me. Created a file, words in vi with separated by multiple lines. `cat file | tr -s '\r' '\n'` returned the correct output.